# Grouping list items with zipWithIndex

Tags: scala

I have a following list which needs grouped in based on the index. The grouping is done with i th item with (i+6)th item( list size is a multiple of 6).

```
val list = List("a" ,"b" ,"c" ,"d" ,"e" ,"f" ,"g" ,"h" ,"i" ,"j" ,"k","l")
```

Expected result:

```
    "a" , "g"
    "b" , "h"
    "c" , "i"
    "d" , "j"
    "e" , "k"
    "f" , "l"
```

I could able to group a single item using

```
list.view.zipWithIndex.filter { _._2 % 6 == 0 }.map { _._1}.force
```

which gives the result

```
Seq[String] = List(a, g)
```

Not sure how to get the desired result for all the items at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.grouped(6).toList.transpose`

grouped(6) will break the list up by 6 elements each time, and transpose transforms the list from

`List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b, c, d, e, f), List(g, h, i, j, k, l))`

to

`List[List[String]] = List(List(a, g), List(b, h), List(c, i), List(d, j), List(e, k), List(f, l))`

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @RyanTheLeach is definitely the way to go if you are guaranteed that the length of the input list is a multiple of the desired grouping factor.

If you don't have that guarantee then you might have to roll your own.

```
val list :List[String] = List("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")  //short List
val mapLst = list.zipWithIndex
                 .foldRight(Map[Int,List[String]]().withDefaultValue(Nil)){
  case ((s,i),m) => m + (i%6 -> (s :: m(i%6)))
}
val grouped = mapLst.keys.toList.sorted.map(mapLst)
//grouped: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, g), List(b, h), List(c), List(d), List(e), List(f))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val list = List("a" ,"b" ,"c" ,"d" ,"e" ,"f" ,"g" ,"h" ,"i" ,"j" ,"k","l") 
def groupList(list:List[String],m:Int) = for(j<-(0 to m-1).toList) yield{ 
               for(i<-(j to list.size-1 by m).toList) yield list(i)
              }
```

### In SCALA REPL:

```
scala> groupList(list,6)
res91: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, g), List(b, h), List(c, i), List(d, j), List(e, k), List(f, l))

scala> groupList(list,3)
res92: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, d, g, j), List(b, e, h, k), List(c, f, i, l))
```

Comment: How slow would you like it to run? (each of thise `list(i)` are O(N), wrapped in O(N^2) pair of loops

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```
val (x,y) = list.splitAt(6);
x.zip(y)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: From the question: _"list size is a multiple of 6"_. Your proposed solution fails if list size is greater than 12.